# Can I use a global object before a trivial constructor?

Tags: c++, static-initialization

I have a (pod) type that needs to be zero-initialized.  However, I would also like to create a global instance of this type, and use that global instance from other global constructors.  My question is whether it is safe to use the type before it has been officially constructed if I employ a constructor that does nothing.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
// file common.h

struct global_flag{};

struct Object{
    Object *next;
    Object();
};

struct List {
    Object *head;
    List() : head(nullptr) {}
    List(global_flag) {}
};

extern List my_list;

extern Object my_object;

inline Object::Object()
    : next(my_list.head)
{
    my_list.head = this;
}

// file A.cc

Object my_object;

// file B.cc

#include <cassert>

List my_list(global_flag{});

int
main()
{
    assert(my_list.head != nullptr);
}
```

Obviously this code would be incorrect if `my_list` were not initialized using `global_flag{}`.  In practice, it seems to work with `global_flag`, and I don't really understand what a compiler could do to mess it up.  After all, `head` will never contain anything other than 0 before `my_object` is constructed, and `List::List(global_flag)` shouldn't change anything.  But of course there are plenty of things that seem like they should be safe but aren't according to the letter of the standard.

My question is: does the above code violate the standard (specifically C++17), and if so, what kind of compiler optimization might break it?

Comment: Not really sure what your sample code is supposed to show here. When you use the `global_flag` constructor the pointer is never initialized to `nullptr`, so obviously the assert will almost always hold. Either way you should have a read on [static order initialization fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).

Comment: If all of the globals are at file scope, in a single compilation unit, their order of construction is guaranteed.   However, the order of construction of objects that are defined in different compilation units is not guaranteed - in any C++ standard.   Your code has undefined behaviour due to relying on a particular order that is not guaranteed.     Rather than using a global - which comes with all sorts of other down-sides, not just this one - simply provide a constructor (or set of constructors if needed) that performs the zero-initialisation

Comment: Why not use singleton pattern for this?

Comment: There are situations where the singleton pattern is very inconvenient, because I don't want to change an API to use different syntax. @YitshakYarom

Comment: @super Thanks for your (unfortunately contradictory) responses.  I'm assuming super is right and Peter is wrong, but I'd love to have an answer to select that actually references the standard.  Or if my code really has undefined behavior, I'd love to understand what a compiler could actually do to make the assertion fail.  (Assume two different compilation units as suggested by the commets.)

Comment: @Peter see my comment to super, thanks.

Comment: @user3188445 Contradictory? Peter is very much correct, and the link I posted you talks about the exact same thing that he said. Initialization order is unspecified. I just additionally pointed out then fact that I find you example confusing, as I don't see what kind of point it's trying to show/prove.

Comment: @super Well my question is whether the code in my example has undefined or unspecified behavior that could lead to an assertion failure.  You are suggesting no, because the global_flag constructor does not touch my_list.head.  This is what I had hoped, too.  Peter, on the other hand, is suggesting that my code has undefined behavior, which would be very bad.  I'm hoping you are correct and there is no UB in the example.

Comment: I never said it doesn't have UB. It does. I just pointed out that `my_list.head != nullptr` is almost always going to be true, since `my_list.head` is never set to `nullptr` anywhere. That is however unrelated to the fact that `my_object` relies on the fact that `my_list` is already initialized, which you can't rely on due to the static order initialization fiasco that I linked to previously.

Comment: @super Do you want to write an answer explaining that it's UB and I'll select your answer?  Basically wondering which of the 200+ instance of UB in the language spec this corresponds to.  I have looked through the spec, but have so far only found discussion dealing with use after destruction rather than before initialization.  It's certainly seems reasonable that it's UB and just no reasonable compiler makes the assertion fail, but the argument doesn't seem entirely straight-forward.